# Querying Entity Framework with an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to use Entity Framework for the first time, and have come a bit unstuck.

I have a class AccountDataAccess:

```
public class AccountDataAccess
{
    public IEnumerable<Account> Get(Account account)
    {

    }
}
```

And another class, Account

```
public class Account
{
    string UserName { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }
    string Email { get; set; }
    Session Session { get; set; }
}
```

When AccountDataAccess.Get() is called, one or more of the account parameters' fields could be populated (e.g. only UserName has a value).
Is there a way in Entity Framework to query the database with the search containing only the fields that contain values?

After doing some googling, the only way I can see doing it is something like

```
    public IEnumerable<Account> Get(Account account)
    {
        StringBuilder queryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder("SELECT VALUE account FROM MyDatabase.Account as account WHERE ");
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(account.UserName))
            queryStringBuilder.Append("UserName = " + account.UserName);

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(account.Email))
            queryStringBuilder.Append("Email = " + account.Email);
        ...
        //continue for all fields
        //then call database
    }
```

Obviously this is a terrible way of doing it though. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

So for a full example, if I had

```
Account account1 = new Account() {UserName = "UserA", Email = "UserA@email.com"};
Account account2 = new Account() {UserName = "UserB"};
```

I would expect the query for account1 to be

```
    var _context = new EntityModel();

    return _context.Where(w => w.UserName == account.UserName
            && w.UserName == account1.UserName
            && w.Email == account1.Email
            ).ToList();
```

But the query for account2 to ignore the email field as it isn't populated:

```
    var _context = new EntityModel();

    return _context.Where(w => w.UserName == account2.UserName
            ).ToList();
```

So I guess my question is can I dynamically generate that Where lambda expression to only include fields that have values?

Comment: just a note... it is good practice to prefix your interface with an I... so you should rename the Account interface to IAccount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query isn't processed until you add an evaluative operation like ToList(). So one thing you can do is build out your query similar to the way you would in SQL.

```
var query = _context.Accounts.AsQueryable();

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(account1.UserName))
    query = query.Where(a => a.UserName == account1.UserName);

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(account1.Email))
    query = query.Where(a => a.Email == account1.Email);
```

You could also do the same with query syntax, though it's a bit more verbose.

When you have finished building out your query, run ToList(), ToArray(), etc. on it to actually execute it and read from the database.

Comment: Was hoping there was a more generic way of doing this, but this is best solution for me so far. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying, the peculiarity of Entity Framework is to map a table to a class (or viceversa). Said that, the Account class will have it's corresponding representation in your databaase, and you should access it in a strongly typed manner, by querying the dbsets contained in your context:

```
//Accounts is a dbset representing the db records for the Account table
_context.Accounts.Where(x => x.UserName == account.UserName && x.Password == account.Password && x.Email == account.Email);
```

This to say that an hardcoded sql statement should be used only when something can't be done with EF (table parameters for instance). Now the question :)

Differently from ADO.Net, when you query using EF you get back a single or a list of your POCO (the Account class), with all its fields, either they got a value or not. If the parameter in **Get(Account account)** is your query filter, then you should choose to execute or not the query according to your needs. EF is based on strongly typed queries, if you want something more dynamic you can [look to anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) but keep in mind that the use of inline statements should be the last card to play.
[An overview of Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the entity model and use the entity model in the project and use the LINQ query to pull stuff from the database like:

```
using (var _context = new EntityModel()) {
 var value = from c in _ontext
             select person 
}
```

You need to use the Linq after the entity model has been created. Entity will turn that LINQ into SQL and execute the code.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to add a where clause into the linq expression which looks at only the fields populated in my account object?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand your question, but a query with WHERE in a  Entity Framework Object would be something like this:

```
public class AccountDataAccess
{
    public IEnumerable<Account> Get(Account account)
    {
        var _context = new EntityModel();

        return _context.Where(w => w.UserName == account.UserName
                && w.Password == account.Password
                && w.Email == account.Email
                /* && other you need */
                ).ToList();
    }
}
```

this query will be return a `IEnumerable<Account>`, but this account won't be your account but the account of Entity Framework.

To return your Account you need this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Account> Get(Account account)
    {
        var _context = new List<Account>();

        return _context
            .Where(w => w.UserName == account.UserName
                && w.Password == account.Password
                && w.Email == account.Email
            )
            .Select(s => new Account {
                UserName = s.UserName,
                Password = s.Password,
                Email = s.Email
            }).ToList();
    }
```

But for this to work you need to declare the Account as a class not an interface.

Comment: Oops, changed Account to a class. Edited my question to hopefully be clearer.